# How do I use a more specific struct type in place of a more general one?

Tags: java, c++, struct, declaration, jna

I am working on a windows device manager which will work with java. 
I stick on trying to pass without error SetupDiSetClassInstallParams function. (I am trying disable an device.)

I am running exact same structure(necessary way) in C++ and I do not have any problem.

I am getting ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER error. When I tried get this error in C++ I need to change SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS structs values with wrong ones.

My struct declerations:

```
    public static class SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER extends Structure {

    public static class ByReference extends SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER implements Structure.ByReference {
        public ByReference() {
        }

        public ByReference(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
        }
    }

    public SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER() {
        cbSize = size();
    }

    public SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER(Pointer memory) {
        super(memory);
        read();
    }

    public int cbSize;
    public long InstallFunction; **/* <-- this should be int or else buffer size changes, dll cannot place variables on right places. */**

    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "cbSize", "InstallFunction" });
    }
}

public static class SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS extends Structure {

    public static class ByReference extends SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS implements Structure.ByReference {
        public ByReference() {
        }

        public ByReference(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
        }
    }

    public SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS() {
    }

    public SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS(Pointer memory) {
        super(memory);
        read();
    }

    public SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER ClassInstallHeader = new SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER();
    public int StateChange;
    public int Scope;
    public int HwProfile;

    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ClassInstallHeader", "StateChange", "Scope", "HwProfile" });
    }
}
```

My function decleration:

```
boolean SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(WinNT.HANDLE hDevInfo, Pointer deviceInfoData, Pointer classInstallHeader, int size);
```

How do I calling this function:

```
    SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS spPropChangeParams = new SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS(); 
    spPropChangeParams.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DISetupApi.DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
    spPropChangeParams.Scope = DISetupApi.DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL;
    spPropChangeParams.HwProfile = 0;
    spPropChangeParams.StateChange = DISetupApi.DICS_DISABLE;
    int spPropChangeParamsSize = spPropChangeParams.size();
    SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER classInstallHeaderReference = new SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER(spPropChangeParams.getPointer());

    setupApi.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDevInfo, device.getSPDeviceInfoData().getPointer(), classInstallHeaderReference.getPointer(),
            spPropChangeParamsSize);
```

How It works in c++:

```
SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS spPropChangeParams;    
spPropChangeParams.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
spPropChangeParams.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
spPropChangeParams.Scope = DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL;
spPropChangeParams.HwProfile = 0; 
spPropChangeParams.StateChange = DICS_DISABLE;

SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDeviceInfo, &device.getDeviceInfoData(), (SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER*)&spPropChangeParams, sizeof(spPropChangeParams));
```

Actually I mixed and matched too many ways these structs and function I changed variable types of structs and parameter types of function at the end I could not get anything but error. I cannot find what is my mistake. Could you please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your native (`C`) declarations as well.  Some of the most common mapping problems involve using `struct *` where `struct` is required or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, I do not declared any C struct etc., all comes from Windows' SetupAPI.dll .
Links Are:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're passing around a `Structure`, don't use `Structure.getPointer()` unless you have to.  When you do that, JNA can't automatically synch the native and Java data, and it's error-prone to remember where to do that yourself.  In your case, whatever is in the Java fields never gets copied to native memory in your call to `setupApi.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams`.

Change your function mapping to this:

```
boolean SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(WinNT.HANDLE hDevInfo, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER classInstallHeader, int size);
```

and change the invocation to this:

```
setupApi.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDevInfo, device.getSPDeviceInfoData(), classInstallHeaderReference,             spPropChangeParamsSize);
```

**EDIT**

If you stick to your original struct definition (where `SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER` is a field), you need to add a function mapping to the interface (extend the interface and create your own instance of the native library):

```
public interface MySetupApi extends SetupApi {
    MySetupApi INSTANCE = (MySetupApi)Native.loadLibrary(MySetupApi.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    boolean SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(WinNT.HANDLE hDevInfo, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS propChangeParams, int size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
There is a trick about function mapping for SetupDiSetClassInstallParams function. It takes SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER struct with casting SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS struct. Otherwise function is not working.

I am using

`SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER classInstallHeaderReference = new SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER(spPropChangeParams.getPointer());`

line for doing that. Anyway both way it is not working.

Comment: If you only pass in a `struct` field from a `struct`, only that inner `struct` will by synched.  See updated answer.

Comment: I already have a interface as MySetupAPI it includes all my code above. I find my mistake. Even I know it should be an int value "public long InstallFunction;"  variable in my SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER class. When I could not make it work, I tested it as long. After your answer I realized I can test my code in custom DLL and I wrote one. I saw my variables places is slipping to next one and buffer is bigger than it should be. I change long to int and mapped function like you sad. It works! Mean time it work as .ByReference() too. Thank you so much.

Comment: And there is an important thing: JNA DO NOT NEED CASTING structs when sending DLL, JNA sends it like void pointer and parses what ever it comes. Thanks to it I am declaring
`SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDeviceInfo, &device.getDeviceInfoData(), (SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER*)&spPropChangeParams, sizeof(spPropChangeParams));` C function as `boolean SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(WinNT.HANDLE hDevInfo, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS propChangeParams, int size);` in Java.